# Why Seq.map only evaluates 5 element?

Tags: f#

This code:

```
[0..100]
|> Seq.map (fun i -> printfn "%A" i)
```

iterates only 5 elements:

```
> [0..100]
- |> Seq.map (fun i -> printfn "%A" i);;
0
1
2
3
4
val it : seq<unit> = seq [(); (); (); (); ...]
```

Why? How can I force it to eval all elements?

Comment: First you should use seq iter for that but assume it is an example simply. 

Seq are lazy and simple realize as a list or array is the simplest choice. So pipe to List.ofSeq

Comment: I know i can use Seq.iter, just wondering out loud if i can acieve the same for Seq.map. You know we can always count on these functional ppl to come up with something novel. At my standard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This happens here**: The expression

```
[0..100] |> Seq.map (fun i -> printfn "%A" i)
```

computes into a sequence of units, visualized as "()". This is not what you normally want. You can see that the function inside the map returns units by FSI's (f# interactive) output:

```
val it : seq<unit> = seq [(); (); (); (); ...]
```

You would get the same result if you write

```
[0..100] |> Seq.map (fun _ -> ())
```

But in contrast to (fun _ -> ()), the function (fun i -> printfn "%A" i) has the **side effect** of printing to the console. This is why you see the numbers printed *before* the result [(); (); (); ()]

The reason why there are 5 numbers printed is an FSI internal: When it prints sequences, which are enumerable collections, it just enumerates the first few. Here it enumerates the first 5 elements  and displays the first 4, which is [(); (); (); ()]

**What you really want** is a map function that accepts a value and returns a new value, in other words a function that **maps** one value to another value:

```
[0..100] |> Seq.map (fun i -> i * 2)
val it : seq<int> = seq [0; 2; 4; 6; ...]
```

As you see, this returns a result of sequence. Again, FSI only shows the first few elements of the sequence. If you transform the sequence into a list you see more elements (but still not all here, since 100 are so many):

```
[0..100] |> Seq.map (fun i -> i * 2) |> Seq.toList 
val it : int list =
  [0; 2; 4; 6; 8; 10; 12; 14; 16; 18; 20; 22; 24; 26; 28; 30; 32; 34; 36; 38;
  40; 42; 44; 46; 48; 50; 52; 54; 56; 58; 60; 62; 64; 66; 68; 70; 72; 74; 76;
  78; 80; 82; 84; 86; 88; 90; 92; 94; 96; 98; 100; 102; 104; 106; 108; 110;
  112; 114; 116; 118; 120; 122; 124; 126; 128; 130; 132; 134; 136; 138; 140;
  142; 144; 146; 148; 150; 152; 154; 156; 158; 160; 162; 164; 166; 168; 170;
  172; 174; 176; 178; 180; 182; 184; 186; 188; 190; 192; 194; 196; 198; ...]
```

This abbreviation comes from FSI, which terminates the length of output of expressions. You can configure the length of these outputs with fsi.PrintLength, PrintWidth and so on. See the docs.

If you want to enumerate all elements of a sequence of list you can write utility functions like

```
let plo xs  = xs |> Seq.iter (printfn "%O") 
[0..10] |> Seq.map (fun i -> i * 2) |> Seq.toList |> plo
> 
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
val it : unit = ()
```

Comment: ah the phrase " return a new value" nails it. thanks.

Comment: What is the benefit of defining `plo` rather than just piping directly to `Seq.iter (printfn "%O")`?

Comment: benefit is that plo is 3 letters. Its a utility function I use frequently in scripts. i often want to display all members of a sequence. AFAIR it started as a function for lists (print list of objects) and then generalized to sequences.

Answer (score 0):

if you use replace **Seq** with **List**, it forces to eval all elements

[image]

- List has a fixed number of items, it make sense to process them all.
- Seq is dealing with IEnumerable, which allows to have infinite items,
  so it does not even try.

[image]